# geocoder call does not work in for loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I am working on project of tracking multiple devices with their last location address, name, time etc. To display address, I'm using Reverse Geocoding (Last location lat long comes from mysql db). Code works for single device tracking but when I am trying to display all devices at a time, it displays only first devices address. After that, for loop stops. I don't get idea that where is I'm wrong. Point me my mistake and correct me if anyone knows. Here is my full javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
function load() {
            var abc;
            var pqr;
            function getLocation() {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            }
            function showPosition(position) {
                abc = position.coords.latitude;
                pqr = position.coords.longitude;
                googlemap(abc, pqr);
            }
            getLocation();
        }

        function googlemap(lat, lng) {
            var x = document.getElementById("myForm");
            var text = '';
            for (var k = 0; k < x.length; k++) {
                text += x[k].value;
                if (k != (x.length - 1)) {
                    text += ",";
                }
            }

            var names = new Array();
            var colors = new Array();
            var imeis = new Array();
            var times = new Array();
            var point;

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                zoom: 6,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            var iconsetngs = {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW
            };

            setInterval(function () {
                downloadUrl("points.php?data=" + text, function (data) {
                    var xml = data.responseXML;
                    var points = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("point");
                    flightPlanCoordinates = new Array();
                    var imo = '';
                    var w = -1;
                    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                        if (parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("imei")) != imo) {
                            names.push(points[i].getAttribute("name"));
                            times.push(points[i].getAttribute("time"));
                            colors.push(points[i].getAttribute("color"));
                            imeis.push(parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("imei")));
                            imo = parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("imei"));
                            w++;
                            flightPlanCoordinates[w] = new Array();
                        }
                        point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                                parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lon"))
                                );
                        flightPlanCoordinates[w].push(point);
                    }

                    for (var j = 0; j < imeis.length; j++) {
                        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                            path: flightPlanCoordinates[j],
                            geodesic: true,
                            strokeColor: colors[j],
                            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                            strokeWeight: 2,
                            icons: [{
                                    icon: iconsetngs,
                                    repeat: '35px',
                                    offset: '100%'}]
                        });

                        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': flightPlanCoordinates[j][(flightPlanCoordinates[j].length) - 1]}, function (results, status) {
                            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                if (results[1]) {
                                    map.setZoom(7);
                                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                        position: flightPlanCoordinates[j][(flightPlanCoordinates[j].length) - 1],
                                        map: map
                                    });
                                    var contentString = names[j] + times[j] + results[1].formatted_address;
                                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                        content: contentString
                                    });
                                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                } else {
                                    alert('No results found');
                                }
                            } else {
                                alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                            }
                        });

                        flightPath.setMap(map);
                        geocoder.setMap(map);

                    }
                });
                names = [];
                imeis = [];
                times = [];
                colors = [];
                flightPlanCoordinates = [];
            }, 10 * 1000);
        }


        function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;
            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (request.readyState == 4) {
                    request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                    callback(request, request.status);
                }
            };
            request.open('GET', url, true);
            request.send(null);
        }

        function doNothing() {
        }    </script>
<body onload="load();">
    <form method="post" id="myForm" class="myForm" name="myForm">
        <select name="dvc">
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <?php
            $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM devices");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['device_imei']; ?>"><?php echo $row['device_name']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <input type="date" name="exct" value="<?php echo $date; ?>"/>
        From:
        <input type="date" name="from" />
        To:
        <input type="date" name="to" />
    </form>
    <button onclick="load();">Submit</button>

    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you post some of your HTML and some sample data, too? I don't see any actual errors in your code (though some of your choices perplex me a bit) but if there were some runnable code (a snippet or link to a jsFiddle example, maybe) it'd help.

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/2020820/steve-k  I have edited my HTML code too.. AND mysql data comes from XML

Comment: @Steve K  Is there any error in my code? If not then why it doesn't work after geocoder.setMap(map); statement. After that statement, it doesn't go for j=1 in for loop (imeis.length is 2).

Comment: There is a possible error in your code: a race condition. Callbacks are not executed synchronously. So your callback is registered, but by the time they all execute, j is whatever its max value is going to be, and you just make the same call over and over.

Comment: If you can suggest me solution(changed code) of this problem, it will be good for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables currently are dependent on the value of `j` at the time the callback executes, which may not be until the actual `for` loop finishes and `j` is at its maximum value. Instead you need to cause them to have their own scope. Javascript doesn't have block scoping, so you need to wrap it in another function call like this:

```
var createGeocodeCallback = function(n){
    return function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
                map.setZoom(7);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: flightPlanCoordinates[n][(flightPlanCoordinates[n].length) - 1],
                    map: map
                });
                var contentString = names[n] + times[n] + results[n].formatted_address;
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString
                });
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            } else {
                alert('No results found');
            }
        } else {
            alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
    };
}
```

And then in your second loop for your `googlemap()` function, you can do this:

```
for (var j = 0; j < imeis.length; j++) {
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates[j],
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: colors[j],
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        icons: [{
                icon: iconsetngs,
                repeat: '35px',
                offset: '100%'}]
    });

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': flightPlanCoordinates[j][(flightPlanCoordinates[j].length) - 1]}, createGeocodeCallback(j));

    flightPath.setMap(map);
    geocoder.setMap(map);

}
```

It would probably be easier and cleaner for you to store your data as one array of objects to process (and access `item.name`, `item.time`, `item.flightPlanCoordinates`, etc) so you could just create your callbacks using `Array.forEach()` which takes care of the whole scoping thing for you.

Comment: Got Success. Thank You for your suggestion. All Problem was due to geocoder.setMap(map); statement. There was no any need of it. That statement was wrong. So Javascript doesn't executed from that anymore.

Comment: How to deal with OVER QUERY LIMIT problem in this code? Only thing I know is that I have to do something in else part of if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK). But what to do?